# dockerized blazor wasm over https doesn't work

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, https, blazor-webassembly

I need to run a blazor wasm hosted pwa in a docker container and make it work over https. I followed this [Quick Start](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md) But it doesn't seem to work as expected for blazor. The exact same steps work for other asp.net core projects though (like the webapi project).

Here are the steps to reproduce:

- Inside a folder `Foo/` Create a sample blazor wasm hosted pwa:

  `dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted --pwa`
- Create a docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /src

COPY ./Shared/Foo.Shared.csproj Shared/
COPY ./Client/Foo.Client.csproj Client/
COPY ./Server/Foo.Server.csproj Server/
COPY ./Foo.sln .

RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .

RUN dotnet build -c Release --no-restore

RUN dotnet publish -c Release --no-build ./Server -o /publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-alpine as runner
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /publish .

ENTRYPOINT dotnet Foo.Server.dll
```

- Create an image from the dockerfile:

  `docker build -t Foo:latest .`
- To make it work with https, we need a certificate. So create one for local development:

  `dotnet dev-certs https -ep ./.aspnet/https/Foo.Server.pfx -p Password`

  `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

Because the certificate name should be the same as the Assembly name and Foo.Server is the name of the assembly (since the server project is what will be running and serving the client project's files), I'm I right ?

- Next, add the password of the certificate in user secrets:

  `cd Server/`

  `dotnet user-secrets init`

  `dotnet user-secrets set "Kestrel:Certificates:Default:Password" "Password"`
- Now, run the container and mount the certificate's folder as a volume so that Kestrel finds it. Mount the UserSecrets as well to provide the certificate's password:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 -p 8001:443 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8001 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -v "C:\Absolute\Path\To\Foo\.aspnet\https":/root/.aspnet/https/ -v "C:\Absolute\Path\To\UserSecrets":/root/.microsoft/usersecrets/ Foo:latest
```

**Expected behaviour** : The container starts and the app is accessible via https on port 8001.

**Actual behaviour** : An exception is thrown saying that no certificate found.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, 
and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
      To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
      For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)      
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate 
was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable`1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at foo.Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/Server/Program.cs:line 16
```

**Edit** : I'm on windows 10 and .Net5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to add the path to the certificate along with the password:

```
dotnet user-secrets set "Kestrel:Certificates:Default:Path" "/root/.aspnet/https/Foo.Server.pfx"
```

In other types projects (other than blazor) I didn't have to add explicitly this path. I think because `/root/.aspnet/https` was taken as the default folder to look for a certificate in if no path was mentionned. But for the blazor project it does not, apparently.